# SharePoint 2019 , SQL 2017 , Always Encrypted

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Does SharePoint 2019 with SQL 2017 Enterprise edition support the Always Encrypted ?

Answer (score 0):

I've setup TDE encryption in SQL 2017 enterprise with SP 2019 and had no issues.

Comment: I understand that TDE works , and how about the Always Encrypted ?

Answer (score 0):

Always Encrypted is not supported for SharePoint.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Premier-Field-Engineering/SharePoint-2013-2016-and-SQL-Server-2016-Supportability-with/ba-p/333312

User Voice:

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/330318-sharepoint-administration/suggestions/16485835-support-for-sql-2016-always-encrypt